# Vector erase loop gives an error, what does it mean?

Tags: c++, vector

when looping through a vector to erase an element, I get an error.

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (std::vector<bullet>::iterator it = 
 bullets.begin();it!=bullets.end();i++)
    {
        for (std::vector<bullet>::iterator it2 = 
 enemies.begin();it2!=enemies.end(); j++)
        {
            if (abs(bullets[i].pos.x - enemies[j].pos.x) < 5.f && abs(bullets[i].pos.y - enemies[j].pos.y)<5.f)
            {
                enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + j-1);
                enemies.shrink_to_fit();
                bullets.erase(bullets.begin()+i-1);
                bullets.shrink_to_fit();
            }
        };
    }
```

[image: error message]

Comment: `xxx.begin() + 0 - 1` == access before begin. I don't understand your `for` loops at all. Why you increment indexes instead of iterators, why you use index in `erase()` instead of iterator??? Why you have iterators if you don't use them?

Comment: Also : read the [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) documentation - especially the part where it mentions which iterators are invalidated.

Comment: Read what an *erase remove idiom* does.

Comment: Shrink to fit saves memory at the cost ( sometimes high cost ) of runtime speed.

Comment: Please read about the basics of iterator invalidation before using iterators or containers. @George `shrink_to_fit()` only *may* do something but *need* not do anything; it's next to useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not make much sense as you are messing up two approaches in there.

You can either use indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
{   
  if (IWantRemoved(myVec[i]))
  {
    myVec.erase(myVec.begin() + i);
  }
}
```

or iterators:

```
for (auto it = myVec.begin(); it != myVec.end();)
{   
  if (IWantRemoved(*it))
  {
    it = myVec.erase(it);
    //this will recapture the iterator after erased element 
    //even if the vector was reallocated
  }
  else
  {
    ++it; //you cannot do this within for loop as you normally would because the iterator invalidation in case of element deletion.
  }
}
```

but using both at the same time does not really make much sense.

Comment: Why can't they use iterators for this? A good answer would explain that (although sure, the question doesn't need asked again in the 1st place)

Comment: @underscore_d: what do you mean? I did write that they can use iterators and added a sample code explaining how to use them.

Comment: I'm using both to get the item in the bullets and enemies vectors. is there a way to use iterators as indices to get an item from a vector?

Comment: @fes dfadfa yes there is, you write *it to access the item pointed to by the iterator it. The lines IWantRemoved(myvec[i]) and IWantRemoved(*it) in my sample code are equivallent.

Comment: with this new code, I don't get an error anymore, the program just freezes...

for (auto it = bullets.begin();it!=bullets.end();)
  {
   for (auto it2 = enemies.begin();it2!=enemies.end(); )
   {
    if (abs((*it).pos.x - (*it2).pos.x) < 5.f && abs((*it).pos.y - (*it2).pos.y)<5.f)
    {
     it2 = enemies.erase(it2);
     
     it = bullets.erase(it);
     
    }
    
   };
  }

Comment: @fes dfadfa almost there, only you still need to increment the iterators in case nothing was erased (otherwise your for loop would run indefinitely testing the same element over and over again). By the way your original for loop would have had similar problem, as the stop condition is the last iterator and you never change the iterator within the loop.

Comment: @Mori ok i added 'else
    {
     ++it;
     ++it2;
    }'
now i get an error saying:"can't dereference out of range vector iterator "

Comment: try this: for (auto it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end();)
{
 bool itWasErased = false;
 for (auto it2 = enemies.begin(); it2 != enemies.end();) 
 { 
  if (abs((*it).pos.x - (*it2).pos.x) < 5.f && abs((*it).pos.y - (*it2).pos.y)<5.f) 
  { 
   it2 = enemies.erase(it2); 
   it = bullets.erase(it); 
   itWasErased = true;
  } 
  else ++it2;
 }
 if (!itWasErased) ++it;
}

Comment: @Mori now it gives the same error, but only on the .erase()

Comment: My fault, ad break; after itWasErased = true;